# How to fix The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x000002002A303F48>?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Below is my code and I keep getting an error that I can't fix

```
# define model

def model_build_train_test(X_train, y_train, X_test):
model= Sequential()
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu', input_dim = X_train.shape[1]))
model.add(Dense(700, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
          
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])  

#Fitting model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 500, epochs=10, verbose=1)

# Generating cat from comments
y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(X_test), axis = -1)
return y_pred

y_pred = model_build_train_test(X_train, y_train, X_test)
```

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure how it could be fixed

```
<ipython-input-111-c05649d83d57> in model_build_train_test(X_train, y_train, X_test)
      3 def model_build_train_test(X_train, y_train, X_test):
      4     model= Sequential()
----> 5     model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu', input_dim = X_train.shape[1]))
      6     model.add(Dense(700, activation='relu'))
      7     model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    159       raise TypeError('The added layer must be '
    160                       'an instance of class Layer. '
--> 161                       'Found: ' + str(layer))
    162 
    163     tf_utils.assert_no_legacy_layers([layer])

TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x000002002A303F48>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63761504/typeerror-the-added-layer-must-be-an-instance-of-class-layer-found-keras-lay

Comment: I think you should specify what version of tensorflow or keras version your using more information helps